# How to pass a params to angular service and change a variable inside the service

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I want to invoke a MyService inside a controller and change "var text" value ,using a a varible from the controller .
which changes i have to do inside the service ,and how to invoke the service in the controller with the new var  ...

```
app.factory('Share', function(){
    var text = "";
    return {
        get: function(){
            return text;
        },
        set: function(value){
            text=value;
            console.log(text);
        },
        value:text
    };
});
```

this is my Controller where i want to invoke to service and change the text value

```
    app.controller('EventCtrl', ['$scope', 'EventService',function 
   ($scope,EventService,Share) {

   var baseUrl = '';

   $scope.getEvents=function()
   {
    var apiRoute = 'http://localhost:9811/notification/notification/';
    var _Event = EventService.getAll(apiRoute);
    _Event.then(function (response) {
           var data = response.data;
             //i want to sned response.data to var text  to change the 
    value of text
            Share.set(data)
            $scope.text=Share.get()

        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        });

   }
   $scope.getEvents()

    }]);
```

this my second controller

```
app.controller('selectFilterController',
['NgTableParams','Share','$scope',function($scope, $filter, $q, 
NgTableParams, Share) {
        $scope.events=Share.get()
        console.log($scope.events)
        $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({page: 1, count: 10}, 
        {data: data})      
      }])
```

No data in the second controller $scope.events is empty

```
  app.controller('selectFilterController',
  ['$scope','$filter','$q','NgTableParams','Share',function($scope, 
  $filter, $q, NgTableParams,Share) {
        $scope.events=Share.get()
        console.log($scope.events)
        $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({page: 1, count: 10}, 
  {data: $scope.events});

      }])
```

Comment: 1. remove `, value:text`. 2. `share.set(someNewValue)`. What have you tried? What's the problem you're facing? What don't you understand? Where's your code?

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet . i got always an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Comment: Because you forgot to add 'Share' to the array of dependencies of yout controller, after 'EventService', and before the function. Do yourself a favor, and use the simple syntax, without arrays. Use ng-annotate to make your code minifiable. That will eliminate this class of freuent bugs.

Comment: Great now in the service MyService the value of Text has changed thanks ... i am using this service to send data between two controlller ....so it works for the first controller 'EventCtrl´...but in second controller when i invoke MyService i still have : TypeError: Cannot read property 'get ' of undefined

Comment: You probably made the same mistake, but I can't see the code of the second controller, so how could I know?

Comment: You probably made the same mistake, but I can't see the code of the second controller, so how could I know?

Comment: i added the code of the second controller :) @JBNizet

Comment: Seriously, after I pointed to the mistake in the first controller, and said you probably made the same mistake in the second one, you should be able to figure that out by yourself. Just read your code. The array of dependencies is `'NgTableParams','Share','$scope'`. Does that match with the arguments of the function: `$scope, $filter, $q, 
NgTableParams, Share`? No. You have 3 elements in the array, and 5 in the function arguments. And the order is completely different, too.

Comment: Thnks ,i am beginner with angular , ihave jsut started ..

Comment: it is ok now with errors ,...but no data in my second controlller  app.controller('selectFilterController',['$scope','$filter','$q','NgTableParams','Share',function($scope, $filter, $q, NgTableParams,Share) {


            // $scope.names = [{id: "", title: ""}, {id: 'Moroni', title: 'Moroni'}, {id: 'Enos', title: 'Enos'}, {id: 'Nephi', title: 'Nephi'}];
            $scope.events=Share.get()
            console.log($scope.events)
            $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({page: 1, count: 10}, {data: $scope.events});
            
          }])

Comment: How did you go from the first controller setting the value, to the second reading the value? If you refreshed the page, everything is lost: the service state is not serialized on disk. It's stored in memory only. If you didn't go throught the code setting the value before going through the code reading the value, that can't work either. I suggest you take a step back, and start reading the angular documentation before proceeding further.

Comment: Update the code to the lastest version so we could see.